# Is the max of two supermodular functions supermodular?

Tags: oc.optimization-and-control, convex-optimization, combinatorial-optimization, economics

A function $f: \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is  *supermodular* if for every $x'>x$ and $y'>y$,
$$f(x',y') + f(x,y) > f(x',y) + f(x,y').$$

Suppose $f$ and $g$ are supermodular, non-negative and increasing in both arguments.
Is the function
$$
h(x,y) = \max\bigl( f(x,y) , g(x,y) \bigr)
$$
supermodular?

Answer (score 3):

I think the answer is **no.**  Let $f$ be a supermodular, non-negative and increasing (in both arguments) function satisfying $f(0,0)=1, f(0,1)=2, f(1,0)=3$, and $f(1,1)=4.5$.  Let $g$ be defined as $g(x,y):=f(y,x)$.  Then, $h(x,y)= \max (f(x,y), g(x,y))$ is not supermodular, since it is easy to check that

$h(1,1)+h(0,0)=5.5 < 6=h(0,1)+h(1,0).$

Comment: As tony mentioned generally no.but if we assume that $x'=x+1 $,$y=y+1$ , $f(x,y)<=g(x,y)$ and  $g(x,y)=f(y,x)$ and also          $f(a+1,b+1)=f(a+1,b)+f(a,b+1)$                                                         a,b are xory then $h(x,y)=max(f(x,y),g(x,y))$ is also supermodular 